# How to use regular expressions to pull a substring? (screen scraping)

Tags: python, regex, screen-scraping

Hey guys, i'm really trying to understand regular expressions while scraping a site, i've been using it in my code enough to pull the following, but am stuck here. I need to quickly grab this:

```
http://www.example.com/online/store/TitleDetail?detail&sku=123456789
```

from this:

```
('<a href="javascript:if(handleDoubleClick(this.id)){window.location=\'http://www.example.com/online/store/TitleDetail?detail&sku=123456789\';}" id="getTitleDetails_123456789">\r\n\t\t\t            \tcheck store inventory\r\n\t\t\t            </a>', 1)
```

This is where I got confused. any ideas?

Edit: the sku number changes per product so therein lies the trouble for me

Comment: You might find this talk from PyCon 2010 interesting - http://pycon.blip.tv/file/3359320/

Comment: Thanks Cristian, I've been watching this in pieces.. but I hadn't found such a great feed as the one you provided. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://www\.example\.com/online/store/TitleDetail\?detail&sku=\d+
```

use the \d group with a "Greedy" +, to qualify any integer value in the sku field

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions for that, just use string methods:

```
result = html[0].split("window.location='")[1].split("'")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern = re.compile(r"window.location=\\'([^\\]*)")
haystack = r"""<a href="javascript:if(handleDoubleClick(this.id)){window.location=\'http://www.example.com/online/store/TitleDetail?detail&sku=123456789\';}" id="getTitleDetails_123456789">\r\n\t\t\t\tcheck store inventory\r\n\t\t\t</a>"""
url = re.search(pattern, haystack).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

if there are always 9 digits

```
http://www.example.com/online/store/TitleDetail?detail&sku=[0-9]{9}
```

if there are an arbitrary number of digits:

```
http://www.example.com/online/store/TitleDetail?detail&sku=[0-9]*
```

more general:

```
http*?sku=[0-9]*
```

(the ? in *? means it will find shorter matches first, so it is less likely to find a match that spans multiple URLs.)

edit: [0-9]. not [1-9]

Answer (score 0):

http://txt2re.com/ might help you